# Restricting character input in custom Python Qt text editor?

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, bioinformatics, dna-sequence

I am interested in writing a custom gui text editor of sorts for DNA using python and Qt. I would like the editor to restrict user input in the text window to only certain letters (such as ATGC). What would be the best way of doing this?

Comment: I don't know the full rules of writing DNA, however, I believe you should start with "regular expressions". With it you have a powerful tool to validate input text.

Comment: I know how to use regular expressions. I was thinking more along the lines of whether there's some sort of event listener for keyboard input in Qt that would allow me to restrict character input, or whether I need to write my own.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ignore`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qevent.html#ignore) function. For example:

```
def keyPressEvent(self, e):
    if e.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_A:
        e.ignore()
```